# Richfaces Bootstrap vs Primefaces with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: java, jsf, twitter-bootstrap, primefaces, richfaces

Im thinking of starting a new JSF project and want to use Twitter Bootstrap (TB) to have a responsive design. I have used both RichFaces and Primefaces in previous project and they are both nice.

RichFacec Bootstrap http://bootstrap-richfaces.rhcloud.com/ seems to wrap bootstrap components in JSF for a seamless integrated solution.

Primefaces has a TB theme but uses their own (great) components together with the TB CSS for layout.

Has anyone experience of using these frameworks? What is more mature? Any pitfalls? 
Please just don't reply saying drop JSF and use a REST backend ;)

Comment: The RichFaces integration with Bootstrap is one of the goals for RichFaces 5: https://community.jboss.org/thread/213160

Comment: Does it mean RichFaces bootstrap will be integrated in RichFaces 5?

Comment: This question doesn't belong here at all. It can't have a single answer which is acceptable by everyone now and in the future. Look for a discussion forum or a chat box.

Answer (score 0):

Component Wise, I would choose PrimeFaces, they are miles ahead of the competition. Their twitter bootstrap theme needs a bit of work though.